# Electron JS Deep Linking not passing the link atribute when cold starting the app

Tags: windows, electron, deep-linking

I am attempting to open a deep link `example://example.com` in electron, It works perfectly when the aplication is already running however it does not seam to pass the link if it is not. opening the pre-defined variable

```
deeplinkingUrl
```

instead

My whole attempt is as follows

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
// Module with utilities for working with file and directory paths.
const path = require('path')
// Module with utilities for URL resolution and parsing.
const url = require('url')

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow

// Deep linked url
let deeplinkingUrl = "https://example.com/"

const gotTheLock = app.requestSingleInstanceLock()


// Force Single Instance Application

if (!gotTheLock) {
    app.quit()
} else {
    app.on('second-instance', (event, argv, cwd) => {
        if (process.platform == 'win32') {
            deeplinkingUrl = argv.slice(1)
            deeplinkingUrl = deeplinkingUrl[1]
            deeplinkingUrl = deeplinkingUrl.replace("exmaple", "https")
        }
        logEverywhere("#app", deeplinkingUrl)
        mainWindow.loadURL(deeplinkingUrl)

        if (mainWindow) {
            if (mainWindow.isMinimized()) mainWindow.restore()
            mainWindow.focus()
        }
    })
}

function createWindow() {
    // Create the browser window.
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600, icon: __dirname + '/icon.png', })
    mainWindow.loadURL(deeplinkingUrl)
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
    if (process.platform == 'win32') {
        // deeplinkingUrl = process.argv.slice(1)
        // deeplinkingUrl = deeplinkingUrl[1]
        // deeplinkingUrl = deeplinkingUrl.replace("exmaple", "https")
    }
    logEverywhere("#newWindow", deeplinkingUrl)
    mainWindow.loadURL(deeplinkingUrl)
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
    logEverywhere("#argv", process.argv)
    

    // Emitted when the window is closed.
    mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
        // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
        // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
        // when you should delete the corresponding element.
        mainWindow = null
    })
}


app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
    // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
    // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
    }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
    // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open. 
    if (mainWindow === null) {
        createWindow()
    }
})

// Define custom protocol handler. Deep linking works on packaged versions of the application!
app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient('exmaple')

// Protocol handler for osx
app.on('open-url', function (event, url) {
    event.preventDefault()
    deeplinkingUrl = url
    logEverywhere("#app", "open-url# " + deeplinkingUrl)
})

// Log both at dev console and at running node console instance
function logEverywhere(s) {
    console.log(s)
    if (mainWindow && mainWindow.webContents) {
        mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript(`console.log("${s}")`)
    }
}
```

I am not sure where to go off from here.

App is bubilt using

```
"electron-builder": "^23.6.0"
```

and running

```
"electron": "^21.3.1",
```

I am running on Win 10